# MVC и организация базы

Tags: база-данных, php, mvc, mysql

Привет. 
Задаю вопрос т.к. мне похоже не хватает базового понимания "как всё работает".

Ситуация: разрабатываю первый проект используя MVC фреймворк и базу MySQL.

Какие есть данные: *Компании* и *Новости*.

У каждой *Компании* будет несколько фотографий. Следовательно я делаю 3 таблицы в базе:

1. Companies
2. News
3. Photos

В таблице `Photos` делаю поля:

1. id
2. foreign_id (для связи *один ко многим* с `Компаниями`)
3. filename (для имени файла)

Соответственно со стороны кода у меня 3 модели и 3 контроллера. За работу с фотографиями отвечает **PhotosController**

Проблема: теперь хочу чтоб и у *Новостей* были фотографии (конечно не те что у *Компаний* :) ). И тут я подхожу к тому что я не понимаю.

Вопрос: что мне следует сделать в этой ситуации – добавить дополнительную таблицу под картинки для новостей, аналогичную таблице `Photos` и допустим назвать её `Media`.
И связать её с новостями аналогично тому как `Photos` связаны с *Компаниями*?

Или расширить таблицу `Photos` введя туда дополнительное поле *'type'* и обозначить в нём кому принадлежит конкретная запись – *Компании* или *Новости*.

В чём у меня сомнения: если делать доп.таблицу, то придётся делать отдельный контроллер в котором будет дублирование кода контроллера **PhotosController**

Если делать дополнительное поле в таблице `Photos`, то там тоже будут осложнения запросов на выборку данных и всякое такое, не ок.

Как вообще поступают в таких ситуациях чтоб и код был DRY и база была по фен-шую? Подскажите пожалуйста поподробнее!
Спасибо.

Comment: А чего ты не сделаешь контроллера 1)Companies 2)News; каждый контроллер работает и со своими фото, 4 таблицы. Зачем для таких задач плодить контролеры и модели. А фрейм, я так понял, Yii.

Comment: Можно и три контролера и 3 таблицы(фото с типом) но как то не удобно с юзабилити.

Comment: Фреймворк кейк. Там на каждую таблицу создаётся модель. Значит 4 таблицы – 4 модели. Если делать 2 контроллера, то они будут сильно жирными на мой взгляд. Туда же придётся запихнуть и всё что связано с CRUD обычных данных и + ещё работу с CRUD фотографий.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос зачем плодить столько таблиц?

> Какие есть данные: Компании и Новости.

Есть 2 контроллера

- company
- news

Все на этом тишина.

есть модели 3 company,news,photo. 2 таблицы.

```
company
id|name|photo

news
id|title|full|short|photo
```

photo - это поле в которое можно писать массив загруженных фотографий к компании или новости, не важно сколько их нужно! Но для новости именно для анонса хватит одной + в тексте самой новости могут быть фотки, но это уже дело редактора в админке как он загружает фотки.

Модель photo принимает фотки для загрузки и обработки все.

зачем 4ре таблицы то? зачем хранить непонятно что и непонятно где + место занимать в 2-3 раза больше.

А если ты галерею сделаешь то на каждую галерею свою таблицу сделаешь и не одну?

Comment: это не есть очень хорошо хранить в photo массив фоток. Если к каждому фото понадобится описание или еще какая инфа? Посему для фоток нужна отдельная таблица, только для того чтобы понять что чему принадлежит, нужно сделать еще одну колонку, например type, можно даже тип enum, и хранить там значения либо news, либо company. ИМХО конечно же

Comment: Не могу полностью согласиться с ответом. В news мы разве что можем добавить поле под иконку новости, хранить там имя файла-иконки. Одного.

Мне же надо прикреплять к новостям много фоток. 10, а то и 15. И с фирмами тоже самое.

Comment: Вопрос не стоял в том что к каждой фотке нужно описание и прочая лабуда. Да и в этот массив можно добавить. Просто задачи разные и каждая решается своими путями.

Я привел все для примера, не обязательно массив, можно 1 фотку.

А прикрепить фотки то нужно в тексте или как? если в тексте то зачем отдельная таблица под фотки? ИМХО бред, то что должно быть на странице в тексте должно добавляться в редакторе.

Из того что я увидел все можно сделать 2мя таблицами. БД не большая, как я понимаю громадного посещения не будет. вытащить раз данные и все.

Что проще сделать select или select with join?

Comment: Я не говорил что оно будет на странице в тексте. Я говорил про связи. У одной компании много фотографий, у одной новости много фотографий. Фотографии уникальны и не повторяются.

Comment: Даже если и список ссылок то можно обойтись 2мя таблицами.

Comment: Чем 2 таблицы лучше трёх или четырёх? Как мне в 2 таблицы запихивать все имена файлов? Через запятую? А потом при выводе "дробить" эту строку с именами?